# Why won't "F12 Developer Tools" disappear from my screen?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have IE11 (version 11.0.9600.16428) open.  I was running developer tools a couple hours back to debug my webpage and then I closed developer tools.  Now, there is a light gray rectangular bar that says "F12 Developer Tools" that looks like a menu selection that just won't go away.  Even if I change to another program, this "F12 Developer Tools" bar is in the foreground and appears over my current program.  How can I make this thing go away?  Clicking on it will do nothing, it does not look like it is selectable.

**EDIT**

Here is what it looks like.  Note, I am running mspaint at the time and the developer tools still appears over the Paint application.

[image]

Comment: Try reopening IE 11, then open F12 tools again, then do what ever you did earlier when it appears and make a select... then F12 again to close the tools.

In task manager kill:
iexplore.exe (all trees)
explorer.exe
dwm.exe

Then restart them

Comment: @AthomSfere - Ok, killing dwm finally got rid of this pest.  Thanks for the help.  I hope it doesn't return again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a fairly common issue. Something with a drawing not being released. I have seen nothing on how to fully prevent it, but end it the current instance one of the following will generally work:

1. Kill the application that created the drawing
2. Kill explorer.exe
3. Kill DWM.exe (The aero interface essentially)

And then bring them all back.

Comment: You know, maybe I just have too early a version of ie11.  I will have to check when I got that one.  I see at http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/get-release-version-internet-explorer-11-windows-7.htm stuff about ghost images and the like.

Comment: I have seen so many applications do this, I am 99% sure its something in Windows/ .net. I can even recreate it on command with one home grown application

Answer (score 0):

Restart Explorer.exe - go to Task Manager processes tab, kill explorer.exe, select Run from the menu, and type "explorer".

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Didn't work.  Even as everything else disappeared when I killed explorer.exe, it lingered and survived the process kill.

Comment: @demongolem probably because it is iexplore.exe not explorer.exe. Explorer.exe is the Windows shell, iexplore.exe is Internet Explorer.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Maybe some corrupt memory in the GPU.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy I'll keep that in the back of my mind, but I would rather not reboot right now.  The annoyance of this is not as great as the running processes I would lose if my computer were rebooted.

Comment: @AthomSfere Yes, but if I exit Internet Explorer, this annoyance still remains.  It may have been caused by IE, but this problem goes beyond IE.

Comment: @demongolem Yep, once I saw the image I understood your issue.